# Value of oscillating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find what happens to the function 
$f (r) = \sum_{p=0}^\infty (-1)^p \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{n} + \frac{1}{2n}\right)}{(2p+1)!} r^{2p}$ for large $r$ (for $n\geq2$). I think this should give me a constant $f(r)$ for large $r$.

When I plot this in Mathematica for $n=2,3,4$ etc., I get some oscillations for small $r$ (as expected), then it is constant until about $r=35$ at which point I start to get oscillations which get larger and larger, but I think that this is because Mathematica cannot handle the large numbers rather than because the function is not constant.

I cannot use the alternating series test because I need to find the value of $f(r)$, rather than just show that it converges.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right) z^{2n}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}t^{n/2-3/4}z^{2n}e^{-t}\,dt $$
hence:
$$ f(z) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(t^{1/4}z)}{tz}\,e^{-t}\,dt = 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(uz)}{u z}e^{-u^4}\,du$$
and the last integral can be studied through [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_method) (stationary phase), or by exploiting the fact that the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin u}{u}$ is a rectangular wave, while the Fourier transform of $e^{-u^4}$ is a very well-behaved function in the [Schwarz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) (a hypergeometric function, to be precise).

Comment: It really ends up being the definite integral of the FT of the hyper-gaussian over frequencies from $0$ to $z$.

Comment: Annoyingly I started off with the final expression you have, what I wanted to was to find an expression for this for $e^{-u^{2n}}$, $e^{-u^4}$ was just the first example of this. Is there any way to do this without converting it back to the integral form?